# Closed-Form Expression for Recursive Function

Tags: recurrence-relation

> Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following function $S\colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$:
>   $$
> S(m,k) = \begin{cases} 3m & \text{if } k = 0, \\ 4S(\tfrac{m}{2},k-1)+3m & \text{if } k \geq 1. \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find a closed-form expression for $S(m,k)$ using repeated substitution.
>
> Prove the correctness of the expression you obtained.

When using repeated substitution, I found the formula
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{k} 4^i\frac {3m}{2^i}, $$

whereas the solution has the formula,

$$ 6m2^k - 3m.$$

I wrote my sum (as well as the original recurrence relation) in Python, and plugged in values from 0 to a 100 for both $m$ and $k$.

For some reason, the sum gets wrong values starting at $m, k = 47, 47$, and follows a weird pattern after that.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Your python issues are off-topic here. I suggest trying again with exact rational arithmetic (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formulas agree:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k 4^i \frac{3m}{2^i} =
3m \sum_{i=0}^k 2^i  =
3m(2^{k+1}-1) =
6m2^k - 3m.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you explain then why the values no longer match after m and k are equal to 47?

Comment: The answer depends on how python implements arithmetic, so is off-topic here. One possibility is that you're exceeding the precision of the floating point numbers used by python, but this is just a guess.